# How to make the phone vibrate on long press with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, hardware

Is there a way to make the phone vibrates when the `onLongPress` "timer" is reached?

For example:

1- There is a list of items

2- I push and hold one item for a "long press"

3- When the `onLongPress` "timer" is reached, I want the phone vibrates just a little.

Doable?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can wrap your widget (item) that you want to long press in an `GestureDetector` for example, resulting in something like this:

```
class MyVibrateButton extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onLongPress: () => HapticFeedback.vibrate(),
        child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(width: 2.0)),
          width: 100.0,
          height: 50.0,
          child: Text(
            'My Item\nPress me',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Edit:** I just found that you can use the Flutter included `services.dart` package that contains the `HapticFeedback` class which allows you to trigger different native haptic feedbacks on both platforms. For this example you can use the `vibrate()` method. Since you want it to vibrate just a little you may want to also try `lightImpact()` or `mediumImpact()` 
. I’ve edited my previous answer accordingly.